# ALL =(ALL) ALL - does the third ALL give them all access?

Tags: sudo

[image]

When it is three ALL's like this, all the users can sudo to all the commands, right?

When it's just one ALL - it only means all the users without that one group can sudo to just the specified commands, right?

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 5):

This information is found (if somewhat cryptically explained) in the `sudoers` man page.

The first `ALL` is the host on which the command(s) may be run.

The second instance (the `ALL` in parentheses) designates which user the command(s) may be run as.

The final field indicates indicates which command(s) the user may run.

Comment: so that last line with the one ALL - does that mean that group is allowed the subsequent listed commands on the host but they need to enter a password?

Comment: It means the users in the Support group are able to run the commands without needing to enter a password.